# Including Custom Helper Method in Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, helpermethods

I've been attempting to add a helper method to my ruby gem for use with Rails 3.

Here is an example of what I am attempting to achieve:

```
module MyHelper

def my_method
    render :text => "Hello World!"
end

end
```

I've tried prepending MyHelper.rb with:

```
ActionView::Base.send :include, MyHelper
```

And I've also tried adding the above line to an init.rb file without success.

Here is the code from the view... Maybe I am implementing it wrong?

```
<%= yield my_method %>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try

```
ActionView::Helper.send :include, MyHelper
```